# My SSH session into my VM Cloud is suddenly lagging

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

Everyday I log into my SSH session of a Google Cloud VM I maintain (Debian).
Since a week ago, I noticed my performance was lagging as I typed into the VM or when doing something else. I mostly login into this VM to check log files of scheduled scripts I have, and even when I use "cat script.log", what used to take less than 2 seconds now takes at least 5 or 7 seconds, loading the log text.

Pinging different websites bring me an reasonable 10 - 15 ms. I'm pretty sure it's not about my local connection either, everything else I do works fine in my local computer.

A warning started to appear now into my session, saying

```
"Please consider adding the IAP-secured Tunnel User IAM role to start using Cloud IAP for TCP forwarding for better performance.  Learn more Dismiss"
```

I've already configured the IAP secured tunnel to my account, which is the owner account of GCP project.

Another coworker of mine is being able to access the VM without any performance issues whatsoever.

Comment: How do you connect ? Directly from Console using SSH button in the browser or using terminal on your local machine ? Does your coworker uses the same internet connection ? Please provide more details (OS, connection method) and first of all try on another machine if it works.

Comment: My local computer is a Windows 10. I'm at my own home office, using my home internet connection (ethernet cable). My coworker uses her own home connection. 

I've always logged using the console through the SSH button you mentioned. I've also tried using the cloud shell terminal, but the result is still the same.

Connecting from another notebook I have at home (Windows 10) through the console returns the same issue. I guess it is something about my home internet connection? I'm not really savvy about ports and stuff , so I don't really know how to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

**Your issue is in my opinion with the ISP**. For some reason the SSH sessions are lagging.

That's why even other computers using your home ISP lag SSH sessions too. If that was firewall rule interfering you wouldn't be able to connect at all.

You may try to reset all the network hardware in your home and if that doesn't help
run `tracert` command in windows shell and then contact your ISP and pass your findings. It's possible it's something on their end (and if not maybe their's ISP etc).

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor I've opened an ticket with my ISP and I'm waiting them to answer, I'll let you know when that happens!

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem you need to add "IAP-secured Tunnel User" at the project level in IAM for that user.[IAP-secured Tunnel User + See instructions here in a blog I wrote about this.](http://wwwhww.news/u/cwSNkeLNXf#How%20to%20give%20access%20to%20%22VM%20Instances%22%20to%20the%20intern%3F%20with%20%40gmail.com%20email%20address%20(GCP)) That should solve your problem.